# How to resolve JSF1095: The response was already committed by the time (...), thrown in every Request

Tags: mojarra, glassfish-4.1

I've read a lot about how Flash is bugged in Mojarra, but I haven't any problems with it since now. I have a JavaEE-Project (1.8) where I have a @ManagedBean (javax.faces.bean) with @ViewScope (javax.faces.bean) and a function like

```
public void foo() throws IOException{
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(keepMessages);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msg", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, detail));
    redirectController.redirect("index.html");
}
```

The Redirect-Function in redirectController is just

```
public void redirect(String url) throws IOException {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
}
```

I'm calling this function from a xhtml-File by

```
<p:commandLink action="#{bean.foo()}"
               update="@form">
               buttontext
</p:commandLink>
```

When I'm pressing the Button, the redirect works and the message appears, but with this and and every following request I get this message in server.log:

> Warnung:   JSF1095: The response was already committed by the time we tried to set the outgoing cookie for the flash.  Any values stored to the flash will not be available on the next request.

I'm using Glassfish 4.1.1 which runs Mojarra 2.2.12 and Primefaces 5.2.

I'm worried that this could cause sideeffects, other then spamming the log. What am I doing wrong?

PS: Since this is my first post on stackoverflow, I would like to say thank you for all the good answers you gave others in the past which saved me a lot of time and trouble. :-)

Comment: What is the code of your redirectController, more specifically the redirect method? Might be that you do a redirect the servlet way instead of the jsf way and that might be the cause. And please, if you tag it Mojarra, you kind of state it works with MyFaces. Same is true for glassfish (does it work with Wildfly?).

Comment: Damn, I'm sorry I forgot this. I added the function. Did I missunderstood tags? I tagged it glassfish-4.1 because the problem occures on glassfish-4.1 and mojarra because any other related post points to mojarra-version, so i suspected the issue there. Should I remove the tags?